# MySQL: SUM of two COUNT (by distinct value)

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySQL-table saves citations. Each row is one citation, as in:

A = `citer`, B = `cited` (i.e., A cited B).

I know how to obtain numbers on (1) who cited A most often, and on (2) whom did A cite most often:

```
/* (1) who cited A most often? */
SELECT citer,COUNT(citer) AS citations1 FROM `table` WHERE cited='A' GROUP BY citer ORDER BY citations1 DESC

/* (2) whom did A cite most often? */
SELECT cited,COUNT(cited) AS citations2 FROM `table` WHERE citer='A' GROUP BY cited ORDER BY citations2 DESC
```

Now what I want is to get a sum of these two statistics (`citations1` + `citations2`) so that I know who has the most total citation linkages to A.

Example: If B cited A five (5) times, and A cited B three (3) times, then the sum of the A-B-linkage is eight (8).

Would that be possible with a MySQL-formula? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
select person, (sum(citers) + sum(citeds)) as total
from ((select citer as person, count(*) as citers, 0 as citeds
       from citations
       where cited = 'A'
       group by citer
      ) union all
      (select cited, 0, count(*) as citeds
       from citations
       where citer = 'A'
       group by cited
      )
     ) c
group by person
order by total desc;
```

This question is a little tricky.  If you attempt to use a `join`, you will exclude the possibility that the person with the most citation linkages is only a "citer" or only a "cited".

Comment: I didn't check, but joining seems to be of higher performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` the results:

```
select t1.citer as person, t1.citations1 + t2.citations2 as result
from
(
SELECT citer,COUNT(citer) AS citations1 FROM `table` WHERE cited='A' GROUP BY citer ORDER BY citations1 DESC
) t
join
(
SELECT cited,COUNT(cited) AS citations2 FROM `table` WHERE citer='A' GROUP BY cited ORDER BY citations2 DESC
) t2
on t1.citer = t2.cited
```

Answer (score 0):

I used UNION in a sub-query and then the sum of the rows

```
SELECT other, SUM(citations)
FROM (
   SELECT citer other,COUNT(*) AS citations 
   FROM citations 
   WHERE cited='A'        
   GROUP BY citer 
   UNION
   SELECT cited, COUNT(*)
   FROM citations 
   WHERE citer='A' 
   GROUP BY cited) AS uni
GROUP BY other
```